# How to terminate multiple EC2 instances in AWS via CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface, aws-cli

I'm looking for terminating multiple `EC2` instances via `AWS` `CLI`. Yes, can able to terminate an EC2 instance by executing the below command.

**Syntax**:
`aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids <intance id> --profile <profile name>`

**Example**:
`aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids <i-...> --profile xxx`

But I have a big list of instances that I need to terminate so I'm searching for a solution to terminating a batch of EC2 instances by providing the list of instance ids. I tried with multiple instance ids as below but those not working.

- `aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids ("instance-id1", "intance-id2") --profile xxx`
- `aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids ("instance-id1intance-id2") --profile xxx`
- `aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids (instance-id1,intance-id2) --profile xxx`

Kindly let me know if there is any possibility to terminate a batch of instances.

Comment: `aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids "instance-id1" "instance-id2"` / `aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids instance-id1 instance-id2`

Comment: the help is useful here `aws ec2 terminate-instances help`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can able to achieve this by following the below command as recommended by [luk2302](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2442804/luk2302)

`aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids instance-id1 instance-id2 --profile xxx`

Also as recommended by [Alex Bailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1655059/alex-bailey), we can try with the shell script (.sh) or batch (.bat) which will make our job easier.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running all the instance ID's through at once I would create a loop in a shell script to do this.

Assuming you have each instance ID on a separate line in a text file you could do something like:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read ins_id; do
  aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids $ins_id --profile <profile name> || echo "error terminating ${ins_id}"
done < instance_ids.txt
```

That's not tested and I'm not great with shell scripting so if you try using it just try with one or two instances first and see what happens.

Comment: This adds unnecessary complication and creates new failure mechanisms

Comment: It very much depends on how you are running it and the expected outcome as well as how the AWS CLI handles a single error. For example, perhaps the AWS CLI blows up if one of the instance ID's in malformed. Maybe this is okay and maybe it is not. This is one way to achieve what OP is trying to do which is terminate a batch of EC2 instances.

Comment: Additionally, depending on the size of the list, perhaps the AWS CLI would struggle with say 100's of 1000's of instances being provided at once.

Comment: I agree it's one way but I don't think it's a good way. The docs are clear that if the list of instances includes an invalid id then the entire operation will fail with nothing terminated. Also that the list is up to 1000 instances though they do recommend splitting into smaller batches. If this is a regular occurrence I'd strongly recommend terraform / cloudformation / an autoscaling group / something managed.

Comment: I don't think we don't know enough about the use case to say it's not a good way. For example, what if the OP wants to run through 100 instances as a one off job that won't be done again and doesn't want to fail on one instance ID being malformed? Just because something isn't the way you would do it, doesn't mean it isn't a "good" way of achieving something. Personally I wouldn't recommend typing out hundreds of instance ID's or generating a huge command with them all in but it's an equally valid way to achieve the desired outcome.